# Removing Underscore of Files under a Directory

Tags: bash, sed, rename

I want to remove the underscores of the files that there are inside some Directories

I have this:

```
Divulgation
├── Biology
│   └── Dawkins, C. Richard
│       └── Books
│           ├── The_Blind_Watchmaker.pdf
│           ├── The_God_Delusion.pdf
│           └── The_Selfish_Gene_(3rd_Ed.).pdf
├── Chemistry
│   └── Gray, Theodore W
│       └── Books
│           ├── Molecules_The_Elements_and_the_Architecture_of Everything.epub
│           └── The_Elements,_A_Visual_Exploration_of_Every_Known_Atom in_the_Universe.pdf
└── Physics
    ├── Hawking, Stephen
    │   └── Books
    │       ├── A_Brief_History_of_Time_from_the_Big_Bang_to_Black Holes.djvu
    │       ├── My_Brief_History.epub
    │       └── The_Universe_in_a_Nutshell.pdf
    └── Sagan, Carl E
        └── Books
            ├── Billions_and_Billions_Thoughts_on_Life_and_Death_at_the Brink_of_the_Millennium.pdf
            ├── Cosmos.pdf
            └── The_Dragons_of_Eden.epub
```

I want this:
[image]

My Attempt:

```
#!/bin/bash


shopt -s extglob  # allow fancy @(...) construct to specify dirs
shopt -s globstar # add double-asterisk for flexible depth

for f in @(Divulgation)/**/Books/*.pdf           # Search for Filed under Books Directory
do echo "mv "$f" `echo "$f" | sed 's/_/ /g'` "   # Show the command first
         mv "$f" `echo "$f" | sed 's/_/ /g'`     # Rename File by removing Underscores using the s Command
done
```

The error:

```
mv Divulgation/Biology/Dawkins, C. Richard/Books/The_Blind_Watchmaker.pdf Divulgation/Biology/Dawkins, C. Richard/Books/The Blind Watchmaker.pdf 
mv: target 'Watchmaker.pdf' is not a directory
mv Divulgation/Biology/Dawkins, C. Richard/Books/The God Delusion.pdf Divulgation/Biology/Dawkins, C. Richard/Books/The God Delusion.pdf 
mv: target 'Delusion.pdf' is not a directory
mv Divulgation/Biology/Dawkins, C. Richard/Books/The Selfish Gene (3rd Ed.).pdf Divulgation/Biology/Dawkins, C. Richard/Books/The Selfish Gene (3rd Ed.).pdf 
mv: target 'Ed.).pdf' is not a directory
mv Divulgation/Chemistry/Gray, Theodore W/Books/The Elements, A Visual Exploration of Every Known Atom in the Universe.pdf Divulgation/Chemistry/Gray, Theodore W/Books/The Elements, A Visual Exploration of Every Known Atom in the Universe.pdf 
mv: target 'Universe.pdf' is not a directory
mv Divulgation/Physics/Hawking, Stephen/Books/The Universe in a Nutshell.pdf Divulgation/Physics/Hawking, Stephen/Books/The Universe in a Nutshell.pdf 
mv: target 'Nutshell.pdf' is not a directory
mv Divulgation/Physics/Sagan, Carl E/Books/Billions and Billions Thoughts on Life and Death at the Brink of the Millennium.pdf Divulgation/Physics/Sagan, Carl E/Books/Billions and Billions Thoughts on Life and Death at the Brink of the Millennium.pdf 
mv: target 'Millennium.pdf' is not a directory
mv Divulgation/Physics/Sagan, Carl E/Books/Cosmos.pdf Divulgation/Physics/Sagan, Carl E/Books/Cosmos.pdf 
mv: target 'E/Books/Cosmos.pdf' is not a directory
```

Help ... Umm the PDFs are reviews of the Books, not the Books themselves ..

Comment: Please don't post images of text. Please post text as text. `Show the command first` - use `set -x` for that. Don't use \` backticks, use `$(...)` instead. Quote your expansions - the result of backticks undergoes word splitting on spaces, so it all is going to result in a lot "not a directory" messages from `mv`. I wonder, why do you need `extglob` - `@(Divulgation)` is just one element, just `Divulgation`.

Comment: It is hard the show the tree structure of the Directory .. Just the Error I guess

Comment: At first glance it looks like you need to put single quotes directly around (outside of the backticks)

Comment: Yeah, I tought the same, but I was not sure, let me see .. Wait, what backticks?

Comment: I also want to include all files, not only pdfs .. I guess an asterik may work

Comment: I have done this kind of thing many and many times. Let me give you a suggestion. Make a script that outputs another script with the moving commands instead of a script that execute the commands. What I mean is that your script will output a string `mv my_file.pdf my\ file.pdf` for each file you want to move. Then you can check the output and if everything is ok, you make this new script executable and run it, changing the names. With this, not only you can check before renaming but easily rename back to the original name by changing columns 2 and 3 with `awk` and running the script again.

Comment: @RobSweet: You wanted for sure say **double** quotes, as single quotes would have the effect, that the backticks are not evaluated.

Comment: Make **sure** you **really** want to **remove the underscores** leaving **whitespaces in filenames**. While it may make things "look" better to you, it creates a quoting nightmare for working directly with the files from the command line. ("nightmare" may be a bit strong, so lets just say it complicates things quite a bit over working with file that have no whitespace in their names.) So unless you have a very good reason for wanting to inject those complications into your file-management life -- save yourself the grief and leave the filenames with underscores...

Comment: Why on earth would you want to do this? Rather than changing the names to an unworkable mess, just change the presentation when you want to read them.  That is, leave the underscores in place so that you have reasonable names and just do `tree | tr _ ' '` when you want a human to look at them.

Comment: well, the script to add them again should be easy .. something similar to the one presented here

Comment: It's very rare to find someone asking to ADD spaces to file names since file names containing spaces are notoriously much harder to deal with robustly than those without. See the excellent advice above from @DavidC.Rankin and @WilliamPursell! wrt your comment that `the script to add them again should be easy` - don't count on it, for example the seemingly simple `for f in @(Divulgation)/**/Books/*.pdf` wouldn't work if your file names contained spaces.

Answer (score 2):

Great script, almost there.

- Using backticks ` is discouraged. Don't use them. Use `$(..)` instead.
- Always rememebr to quote expansions (and also backticks, if you use them).
- Remember that `echo "$f"` may fail for strange filenames like `-e`. [Use `printf "%s\n" "$f"` instead](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/65803/why-is-printf-better-than-echo). But since it's bash, you can just `<<<"$f"` use a [here string](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Here-Strings).
- You could use `set -x` to see what is happening. I think simple `mv -v` might be more... simple.

You need to quote the backticks. If you don't quote them, shell will do [word splitting](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Word-Splitting) - split the result on spaces into multiple arguments. So for example `ls $(echo "filename with spaces.txt")` will run `ls` with 3 arguments and `ls` will interpret is as 3 separate files - `filename`, `with` and `spaces.txt`.

And replace backticks with `$(...)`:

```
for f in Divulgation/**/Books/*.pdf; do
     mv -v "$f" "$(<<<"$f" sed 's/_/ /g')"
done
```

For substituting single characters, for me using `tr '_' ' '` seems like more "suitable" command then `sed`.

Comment: How do I also rename djvu and epub files?  .. Do I add an asterik at the end ( *.* instead of *.pdf )

Comment: Why not just `for f in Divulgation/**/Books/*.pdf Divulgation/**/Books/*.djvu Divulgation/**/Books/*.epub;` ? With extglob I think you can `Divulgation/**/Books/*.@(pdf|djvu|epub)`. But for anything more complicated consider using `find` for example piped `xargs` instead.

Comment: Without extglob `for f in Divulgation/**/Books/*.{pdf,djvu,epub}`

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (find, rename and GNU parallel):

```
find Divulgation -path '*/Books/*.pdf' | rename -v 's/_/ /g'
```

If you want to parameterize the top directory, use:

```
parallel --dry find {} -path '*/Books/*.pdf' \| rename -v 's/_/ /g' ::: Divulgation SomeotherVulation
```

When satisfied the commands are correct, remove the `--dryrun` option